# playing radio using .pls file by http streaming in window phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i have to play audio file which is the URL and it's relates to (.pls) file format in window phone 7 i have the url(http://174.36.167.220:9000/) of audio which is for radio playing. i have implemented the code for this its working but the sound is going very fast then the normal playback of audio file. other audio url i have try using my code and its working fine

i have used the code which i download from the net and i cannot include here that code because its having three class files within the folder shoutcast

i am playing the audio file from the URL by streaming over HTTP with the following detail

```
Server Status:  Server is currently up and public.
Stream Status:  Stream is up at 32 kbps with 119 of 4000 listeners (116 unique)
Listener Peak:  1518
Average Listen Time:    3h 10m 39s
Stream Title:   670 am KIRN
Content Type:   audio/mpeg
```

please any one help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you need to implement the whole streaming layer from scratch in this scenario because what you have is a 32kbps MP3 stream. Whether you use a background audio agent or a `MediaElement`, both can stream content - just set the source the the URL you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

.pls playlist is not supported in windows media element we have to parse the content and get the stream urls, here i pass a pls url to function and get all stream urls as list we can point media element source to any url and will play the radio

```
  public static async Task<List<string>> GetStreamsFromPLSUrl(string url)
    {



        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = false, AllowAutoRedirect = true };

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();



        try
        {


            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
            List<string> Streamurls = new List<string>();

            string line;
            while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Substring(0, 4).Equals("File"))
                    Streamurls.Add(line.Substring(6));
            }

            return (Streamurls);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + "/n" + ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }
    }
```